# Move movieclip position opposite of mouse coords on other movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse, position

Okay I have a script in which I have added an image to the stage. It is absolute centered. I then have another with is on top but much bigger. I would like the big image to move opposite of my mouse position on the smaller image.

ie: cursor is on bottom left corner the bottom left corner of the larger image is in the same spot. And the same thing for any other area.

I have tried many different ways but to no avail. I have done research but no one has been able to give me a solid answer.

Anyone know of a way to accomplish this. Keep in mind this it needs to work regardless of the image size.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: If your mouse is on the bottom left corner of the small image, the big image's left corner should be at the lower left corner of the stage? A bit like the Navigator in Photoshop?

Comment: Yes similar, it would be like a navigator over the top of the smaller image. It would be as though the big image is masked with the dimensions of the smaller image but not literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using yourMovieclip.mouseX to get the position of the mouse relative to that movieclip

Comment: That's what I have been using I just want to know how others would accomplish this scenario.